# Use Snap-To-Roads-APIs for bike paths

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-roads-api

I would like to use the snap-to-roads functionality to normalize bike paths. Bikes sometimes follow different rules (they may drive in the wrong direction of a one-way street). Is it possible to use "bike rules" in snap-to-roads or would a better way be using the directions API (with bike mode)?

Regards,
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Roads API (snap to road) is not useable for bikes. See the Dokumentation and the demo under: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo

So the directions API is the way to go or use online or offline services.

best regards, Reinhard